# AngularJS: how to update a directive from another controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Well, I'm having some problems updating a progress bar (which is in a directive) from a controller.

here are some code snippets:
my directive:

```
angular.module('TestApp').directive('orderProgress', ['$window', OrderProgress]);

  function OrderProgress($window) {

    var directive = {
      link: link,
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'OrderProgress.html',
      controller: 'ProgressController',
      replace: true
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {}
  }
```

controller for directive:

```
function ProgressController($scope, progressNumberService) {
    $scope.progress = progressNumberService.getProgress();
  }
```

progressNumberService just hides the detail for the amount of "progress":

```
var progress = 20;
  var progressServiceInstance = {
    incProgress: function() {
      progress += 20;
    },
    decProgress: function() {
      progress -= 20;
    },
    getProgress: function() {
      return progress;
    }
  };

  App.value('progressNumberService', progressServiceInstance);
```

of course the controller:

```
function Controller($scope, progressNumberService) {
    $scope.nextStep = function() {
      progressNumberService.incProgress();
    };

    $scope.prevStep = function() {
      progressNumberService.decProgress();
    };
  }
```

I've created an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/LtY4ZUG591Kd3mUKEmEF?p=catalogue

So why doesn't the directive get the update from the 'Controller', when the Next/Prev buttons are pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your issue is that the value is being updated in your .value module, but your directive controller is never calling getProgress once the values are updated. I would suggest using $broadcast and $on to send a message saying that the progress was updated. I tested this and it seemed to do the trick.

Controller:

```
angular.module('TestApp').controller(controllerId2, ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'progressNumberService', ProgressController]);

function ProgressController($scope, $rootScope, progressNumberService) {
  $scope.progress = progressNumberService.getProgress();

  $rootScope.$on("event:progress-change", function() {
    $scope.progress = progressNumberService.getProgress();
  });
}
```

And change your .value to a factory so you can use $rootScope to broadcast

```
App.factory('progressNumberService', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    incProgress: function() {
      progress += 20;
      $rootScope.$broadcast("event:progress-change");
    },
    decProgress: function() {
      progress -= 20;
      $rootScope.$broadcast("event:progress-change");
    },
    getProgress: function() {
      return progress;
    } 
  }
});
```

Here is the updated Plunker [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gBK2vBphYMbM0jEwuULb?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks.  That did work.  My angular knowledge is not at that level (yet).